# How to fetch templates repos from Github API?

Tags: github-api

I want to fetch all repos that are templates from my account.
I tried to fetch single repo according to this https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository
and then filter the response by "is_template" key as it is described in the docs.
The problem is don't get this field in the response, other values are alright.
This is the request I do: `https://api.github.com/repos/my-account/test`
I'm authenticated, i'm on my own account, I try to fetch my own repo.

Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong that I don't have "is_template" in the fetched repo?
2. Is there other way to fetch only templates rather than filtering out all repos?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to opt-in with the preview header to receive the new `is_template` field on the response.

This curl request works for me:

```
$ curl -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.baptiste-preview+json" https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.net | grep "is_template"
  "is_template": false,
```

Whereas this one does not return any output:

```
 curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.net | grep "is_template"
```